# Why is this password check not working as expected?

Tags: perl, cgi

I am trying to expand from php.  Here is a basic problem I have and can not figure it out...

password.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;
$q = new CGI;

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
print '<html>';
print '<head>';
print '<title>Card</title>';
print '</head>';
print '<body>';
print '<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION=/card.pl>';
print '<INPUT TYPE=password NAME=password SIZE=25>';
print '<input type=submit value=Submit>';
print '</FORM>';
print '</body>';
print '</html>';

1;
```

card.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;
$q = new CGI;

$password = $q->param("password");
print $password;
if ($password == pass)
{
  print 'Yup';
}
else
{
  print 'Wrong Password';
}


1;
```

Nothing is passing to card.pl from the password.pl form?  I have used a simular example before with no problem?

More coffee...

Comment: perhaps try out the `....ACTION="/card.pl"`. Also the password.pl lacks the headers section.

Comment: heredoc would be more readable for outputting HTML

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`use strict;`, `use warnings;` and look in your error logs. Also [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) your HTML.

Then you'll be alerted to problems like:

> Bareword "pass" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at card.pl line 7.

You probably want:

```
($password eq 'pass')
```

Answer (score 1):

In my continuing quest to disabuse the abuse of CGI.pm, your first script would be much better as–

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw( :standard );

print
    header(),
    start_html("O HAI CARD"),
    start_form(-action => "card.pl"),
    fieldset(
             legend("None Shall Pass!"),
             password_field(-name => "password",
                            -size => 25),
             submit(-value => "Submit"),
             ),
    end_form(),
    end_html();
```

Your second as, perhaps, just for example, et cetera–

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
my $q = CGI->new;

print
    $q->header,
    $q->start_html("O HAI CARD");

my $password = $q->param("password");

if ( $password eq "pass" )
{
  print $q->h2("You're all good");
}
else
{
  print $q->h2({-style => "color:#a00"},
           "You're all good");
}

print $q->end_html();
```

Or, maybe better, all together–

```
use strict;
use warnings;
no warnings "uninitialized";
use CGI qw( :standard );

print
    header(),
    start_html("O HAI CARD");

print param("password") eq "pass" ?
    h2("Yes!") : h2({-style => "color:#a00"}, ":(");

print 
    start_form(),
    fieldset(
             legend("None Shall Pass!"),
             password_field(-name => "password",
                            -size => 25),
             submit(-value => "Submit"),
             ),
    end_form(),
    end_html();
```

RIF, read the docs: [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI).